# How to differentiate between applications with the same name in applescripts

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to use `tell application "Google Chrome"` in order to script the OS X Chrome app, but this keeps being interpreted as referring to a virtual application with the same name which refers to the windows "Google Chrome" inside a parallels desktop virtual machine. (Parallels Desktop automatically creates dummy OS X applications corresponding to all of the windows programs, so that they can appear running in the OS X dock etc.)

How could I differentiate between applications of the same name in such `tell` statements, based on the application path or some other attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You can use direct path to the application inside Your Apple Script.
This will looke like:

```
set p to "/Applications/Safari.app"
tell application p to activate
```

Here's the link about [AppleScript and POSIX paths](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/external_codes/file_paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you type `tell application "whatever"` and you click compile, if `whatever` does not exists, it will appear a window that let you choose the application. Try this way.

[image]